# Remove a slide in Swiper React

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I want to remove the first slide in react with swiper js. I looked in the API and found swiper.removeSlide(slideIndex), but that doesn't seem to work. I am using the useSwiper hook. But still, I am getting 'swiper.removeSlide is not a function'. Anyone
how I could handle this?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSwiper } from "swiper/react";

const DeleteSlide = ({}) => {
  const swiper = useSwiper();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      swiper.removeSlide(0);

      swiper.activeIndex = 0;
      swiper.initialSlide = 0;
    }, 9000);
  }, []);

  return <></>;
};

export default DeleteSlide;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import 'Manipulation' module.

```
import SwiperCore, { Manipulation } from 'swiper';

SwiperCore.use([ Manipulation ]);
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are passing the array of images for swiper then while passing the array, you can use array.slice(1, images.length-1) so the first image will be excluded

Comment: This works the only thing is that it jumps 1 forward when I remove it. For example the array is [0, 1, 2] and 0 gets deleted when the active is 1 but when 0 gets deleted the active is still 1. Then the array is now [0, 1]. And the active is still 1 so it jumps to the last slide, but it has to stay at the original second slide.